# Removing house numbers from OpenStreetMap using OpenLayers?

Tags: openstreetmap, openlayers-2

I want to remove all the house numbers of the base layer from OpenStreetMap using OpenLayers 2 and if it is posible the points of interest too.

Answer (score 1):

You can't. The images you get are as they are. You will need to style the underlying data yourself.

Comment: Ok, can you tell me how please...

Comment: https://switch2osm.org/

Comment: That would be a different question.